# Travis variables not available in node.js

Tags: node.js, docker, travis-ci

I'm setting up travis environment variables both using console and travis.yml, so when I'm running build on travis all variables are exported, e.g.

[image]

Variables I've set in console are accessible from travis script, since docker containers built are deployed to docker and code is pushed to AWS.

Problem I have is to access these variables from node.js tests that I'm running from the script:

```
before_install:
  - docker build -t mydocker/api-test -f ./server/Dockerfile.dev ./server

script:
  - docker run -e CI=true mydocker/api-test npm test
```

When I try to access those variables using process.env.TEST_ENV or process.env.TEST_VAR or any other, I'm getting undefined.

I'm using this script to run tests from node:

```
"test": "NODE_ENV=test nyc --reporter=html mocha --timeout 10000 \"src/**/*.test.js\" --require @babel/polyfill --require @babel/register --recursive --exit",
```

Comment: You are setting the variables in the travis agent that build the images, not inside the images....if you need to access those values inside of your images, you need to include those values like `docker run --env TEST_VAR --env TEST_ENV mydocker/api-test npm test`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This works. If you convert it to answer, I'll accept it as correct.

Comment: I'll do it tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to declare and expose `ENV` variables to your containers. Tha issue here was that your where exposing `ENV` variables into your `travis` pipelines, but not into your `containers`. In order to expose `ENV` variables to your containers, you have several options:

- Via `Dockerfile`:

  `# default value`

  `ENV hey`

  `# a default value`

  `ENV foo /bar`

  `# or`

  `ENV foo=/bar`
- Set environment variables `(-e, --env, --env-file)`

```
export VAR1=value1
export VAR2=value2

$ docker run --env VAR1 --env VAR2 ubuntu env | grep VAR
VAR1=value1
VAR2=value2
```

From the documentation:

> When running the command, the Docker CLI client checks the value the variable has in your local environment and passes it to the container. If no = is provided and that variable is not exported in your local environment, the variable won’t be set in the container.

You can also load the environment variables from a file. This file should use the syntax =value (which sets the variable to the given value) or  (which takes the value from the local environment), and # for comments.

```
$ cat env.list
# This is a comment
VAR1=value1
VAR2=value2
USER

$ docker run --env-file env.list ubuntu env | grep VAR
VAR1=value1
VAR2=value2
USER=denis
```

> Documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/